# How to use an API from Mashape in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, mashape

I have to use an API from mashape in my app. I have installed maven. I am using Android Studio. What further steps should I take ?

Comment: Please help. Do not ignore :P

Comment: have u found any solution?? Pls post the answer if yes!

Answer (score 1):

simply use the **HTTPPOST** and **HTTPGET** method according to API and add header then you can get JSON

don't use the any library.

Comment: Should i add this dependency com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9 ?